# PHPUnit Larvel execute ONCE before testing

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I use Laravel 8 with PHPUnit 9.3.3

Now I has written in `CreatesApp.php`:

```php
namespace Tests;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

trait CreatesApplication
{
    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
        $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

        Artisan::call('migrate:reset');
        Artisan::call('migrate');

        \App\Models\User::factory(10)->create();
        \App\Models\Post::factory(10)->create();

        return $app;
    }
}
```

And this code executes every test and I want this code executed ONLY before testing:

```php
Artisan::call('migrate:reset');
Artisan::call('migrate');

\App\Models\User::factory(10)->create();
\App\Models\Post::factory(10)->create();
```

Comment: How hard can it be to read the documentation before reinventing the wheel 100000 times ? It is explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test) perfectly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute some commands only once at startup - you can bootstrap tests with your own boostraper: [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/bootstrap.html)

But, your way is not correct:

1. Tests MUST be isolated: migration MUST be executed for each tests
2. For this - add DatabaseMigrations trait to your tests.

   ```
   use DatabaseMigrations;
   ```
3. For create entities - use [seeders](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/seeding#introduction)
4. For seeding database for tests - overwrite setUp method

   ```
   public function setUp(): void
   {
       parent::setUp();
       $this->seed();
   }
   ```

Btw, maybe you frustrated about tests speed with migrations - look at this [article](https://medium.com/@2618094/speed-up-feature-tests-in-laravel-with-docker-compose-and-tmpfs-a845a278d072) - it's dramatically improved performance